# How do put background photo inside of 1 of these boxes React, tried everything?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is the code tried everything, how do u put a background photo

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Photo from "./Emoticons/A.jpg";

class Contact extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contact" style={{ width: "1200px" }}>
        <div className="row ml-5">
          {/* Prva */}
          <div className="col-sm mt-5">
            <div
              style={{
                boxSizing: "content-box",
                boxShadow: "-2px -2px 5px #000000",
                height: "400px",
                width: "345px"
              }}
            >
              <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Info</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Druga */}
          <div className="col-sm mt-5">
            <div
              style={{
                boxSizing: "content-box",
                boxShadow: "-2px -2px 5px #000000",
                height: "400px",
                width: "345px"
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
          {/* Treca */}
          <div className="col-sm mt-5">
            <div
              style={{
                boxSizing: "content-box",
                boxShadow: "-2px -2px 5px #000000",
                height: "400px",
                width: "345px"
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Contact;
```

Tried background:'photo', nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the javascript equivalent of the CSS properties. For example:

```js
const backgroundPhotoUrl = "..."
<div style={{
  backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundPhotoUrl})`,
  backgroundPosition: "center center",
  backgroundSize: "cover",
}}>
  {...}
</div>
```